# resigning in a turn-based game (game centre)

Tags: objective-c, game-center

I have the following code behind my resign button:

```
currentMatch.currentParticipant.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
nextParticipant.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
[currentMatch participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost 
                               nextParticipant:nextParticipant matchData:data
                             completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        [statusLabel setString:@"You resigned"];
                                                    }];
```

It says "You resigned" but the opponent is not given a notification, the turn is just passed to him.  The opponent can now not make any move, otherwise an error is caused.  The only way to finish the game is for the opponent to resign as well.

Can anyone see what is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the above code. The Way Game Center Turn based works is that the next player needs to handle his turn and decide if the game is over now and quit also or continue on with the game (in case of more than 2 players that makes more sense). So it is part of your game code to do that.

You should be able to continue playing as long as you don't set the resigned player as next participant anymore. That you can't do. (And you should set the outcome to GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit instead of Lost if you want to continue the game)

If you really wanted to end the game for all players in that moment you can set all outcomes on the participants of that match as you see fit and then use

```
[currentMatch endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:data completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler];
```

to end the game for all players.